# How do I reset my Bash Profile in Terminal to default?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I messed around with my bash profile (in nano, macOS) a while ago and changed how the Terminal prompt looks. Now, I just want my prompt to be the default, but when I change it in .bash_profile, nothing happens. I'm running macOS Catalina version 10.15.4.

Comment: Have you restarted the terminal?

Comment: Just checking: are you sure you're using bash? zsh is the default for Catalina.

Comment: @DavidPostill What do you mean by restart? How would you do it? I might have but I didn't know if it was "restarting".

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not sure. How would I check?

Comment: What do you get when you execute the command `echo $0`?

Comment: @Glorfindel When I execute the command, I get `-zsh`

Comment: Me too, except that I forgot I was `ssh`ing into an older mac, so I got `-bash`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since macOS Catalina, [zsh is the default shell instead of bash](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features). So changing `~/.bash_profile` doesn't help; you either need to

- change your zsh profile through `open ~/.zshrc`
- change your default shell to bash through `chsh -s /bin/bash`
  It's also possible to [do this via the GUI](https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/) but if you're already in Terminal, this is quicker.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. In zsh, it's actually even easier, as you can just do `PROMPT=" %n "` or whatever you want.